# Any Web & Java IDE's for the ARM architecture on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, ide, arm, development-environment

I am currently running Debian Linux on an ARMv7 microprocessor (aka my android phone. ;))
it really runs great, without a single issue. With surprisingly a great deal amount of application support compiled for arm, as compared to many other arm based linux distros.

I would love to use it for some Web Development, as well as Java programming and compiling, but I am having a bit of trouble trying to find any IDE's that are either architecturally independent or compiled for the ARM processor..

One I am really curious about is, IntelliJ IDEA. But I cant figure out if it is architecturally independent or just x86 support only.

I also believe Netbeans is ready and compiled for NetBeans, but I am not a big user of it so I would prefer to use one of the ones I use more often. but if it comes to it, and it does support arm, I will definitely use it.

So what do you folks know of? Are there any programs that are compiled for arm that will suit this purpose for me? or am I stuck with Vim or something?

Comment: IntelliJ is written in Java.  They have a vendor neutral zip download.

Comment: Thank you. Now that leaves me with Web Development.

Comment: Plenty of web servers written in Java.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I dont need a webserver though.. (despite the fact I actually set up a LAMP stack successfully.) I need a Web Development IDE. not necessarily a server..

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have "sun-java6-jdk" in the arm repository list... :( there is "openjdk-6-jdk" but I hear there are problems with intellij idea and openjdk. I hope this works.

Comment: UNREAL!!! IntelliJ IDEA running fantastic on my Android Phone, with a chrooted Debian Linux mounted loop device. I used "openjdk-6-jdk" as my jdk as I couldnt find Sun-java6-jdk for arm unfortunately.. :( But oh well! It works!!! its loads, no errors, its codes! it runs! it complies! its perfect! very happy guy right now. Thank you all for your input. Ill show a couple screenshots in a bit if someone is still interested. Never say Never folks!

Comment: @insomnia wow, that's awesome. Maybe you should make a post on https://news.ycombinator.com or http://reddit.com/r/programming with a guide. That sounds pretty cool. Post screenshots too.

Comment: @Strelok I dont use those sites, nor have I heard of news.ycombinator.com but I will most definitely look into it. Especially if it would help others. I know you can also install Eclipse, but you must compile from source.. But heres the screens as promised. I merged them together for a full landscape. its actually 3 portraits. whats crazy is I have a horrible spec' phone too. SPH-D600. and it runs great. my information is shown in the terminal. 1. http://i.imgur.com/VjUD8.png   2. http://i.imgur.com/CD6j8.png   3. http://i.imgur.com/PogLk.png   really cool. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it never hurts to try :)

Have you downloaded the JRE for ARM from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/downloads/javase/index.html? Get that and download IntelliJ 11 Community Edition for linux and give it a go.

Comment: Yep. thats all set up. I read that on ARM, JRE 6 is only supported, and JRE7 is not. Also according to many Raspberry Pi users, it is a "headless" java, and not "headful" if that matters in this case..  But I would like to know if IntelliJ is arch independent first before downloading, because since I am using a mobile device, I kind of try to limit my downloading. I prefer not to waste the bandwidth if not needed. As I am already quite a data hog as it is..

Comment: @insomnia if you want to do Java development you need flat rate internet.

Comment: @insomnia both headless and headful downloads are available for both Java SE 6 and 7. As for IntelliJ, it comes in 3 different flavours (Windows, Mac and Linux), but in theory the core of it should be arch independent as it is written in Java. It does come with it's own JRE, so you would have to delete it to force IntelliJ to run using the JRE for ARM that you installed.

Comment: @Strelok Okay I guess I will try it out then! :) Thats why I figured it may be architechtually independent as there is no 32 or 64 versions. So I figured it was arch independent, or just plain old x86.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen um why? I develop in Java without internet connection ALL THE TIME... Why would I need "flat rate internet"? I am positive we develop completely different things, aimed at different things.. I develop for the android platform only. So why would I need fast broadband constantly for that? plus I get 1mb per sec average on my android phone, and actually have an unlimited plan, but if I constantly use my internet and waste bandwidth I could get capped, I am just trying to prevent useless downloading.. So could you please explain what you mean, cuz I am lost at your comment..

Comment: @insomnia you need to search for problem solutions, download third party libraries, look up Javadoc (which almost always link to Oracle), etc. etc.  All the things that used to be in the paper manuals, so not having "no needs to worry" internet limits _me_.  If it doesn't limit you, fine, but it seems to.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No I just wanted to be precise. and actually know that it was arch independent. Plus I dont actually need to do all that on a linux environment on my phone. I could always use a PC. Plus I download all my PDFs, resources, etc. and searching the internet wouldnt take much either. A months worth of simple searching would run me maybe 50mb. I could do all that on dial-up. I do have unlimited plan, but as others have mentioned before on this provider they have been capped before for being hogs. so I try to limit any unneeded downloads. But I am obviously taking a chance now.

Comment: Did anyone get Itellij Idea, Android Studio, or the Android Eclipse Plugin working on an armv7h machine?

Answer (score 2):

On the Samsung Chromebook Arm, Eclipse works when running [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) and Ubuntu. At the command line, enter:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

Ubuntu will automatically install Java JDK 6 for arm. Replacing it with Oracle Java JDK 8 for Arm will improve performance

Alternatively, when using [Chroagh](https://github.com/drinkcat/chroagh) and Arch Linux, Intellij Idea works. At the command line, enter:

```
cd /usr/lib
sudo ln -s libgif.so libgif.so.4
pacman -S intellij-idea-community-edition
```

Intellij Idea install with Open-JDK7 for ARM, but you can replace it with Oracle JDK8 for ARM.

Lastly, I have had no luck installing Android-Studio or the Android SDK for Eclipse on either Ubuntu or Arch. Still searching for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is still a bit early for ARM desktop-class hardware to use for development even if the hw is now strong enough.

I have managed to run some bigger Swing applications on my XE303C Chromebook under Ubuntu 12.04 (OpenJDK7 and now Oracle JDK( for ARM/Linux 8 EA) but I haven't had much success with Java IDEs.

Netbeans 7.3 fails to start on both JREs after the splashscreen.

Eclipse is in the repos though, so it may work. (I am a Netbeans guy so I haven't tried)